# Convert an array of objects to an array of arrays grouped preserving the order - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and I need to convert it into an array of arrays grouped together based on position, but maintaining the order of the items.

This is what I did:

```js
const data = [{
  position: 'left',
  message: 'a'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'b'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'c'
}, {
  position: 'right',
  message: 'd'
}, {
  position: 'right',
  message: 'e'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'f'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'g'
}]

console.log(data.reduce((a, c) => {
  let b = [];
  let d = [];
  if (c.position === 'left') {
    b.push(c.message)
  }
  if (c.position === 'right') {
    d.push(c.message)
  }
  a.push(b)
  return a
}, []))
```

Expected output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g']]
```

The same position elements are grouped together in an array and if the next position is different, it is grouped together in a different array and goes on. For example, 'a' 'b' 'c' are position left and they are grouped inside an array, 'd' 'e' are positioned right, they are grouped together as the second array and 'f' 'g' are left positioned, they are grouped as 3rd array.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless your forcing yourself to use reduce for some intellectual reason, this is going to be way more readable as a plain old for-of loop.

Comment: I'm open to a for loop or anything

Comment: @NickBailey closed variable scope could be one reason. You'd have to push to an array that lives outside the for loop to create an array of arrays. `reduce` is a perfectly valid solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Hard-coding the creation of two arrays won't be enough, especially not inside the `.reduce` callback. If you need to use `.reduce` here (which I wouldn't recommend because it looks a bit convoluted), use the iteration index to check the *last* index to see which `position` was used there. If it's different from the current index's position, push a new array to the accumulator. Finally, unconditionally push the current message to the last array in the accumulator.

```js
const data = [{
  position: 'left',
  message: 'a'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'b'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'c'
}, {
  position: 'right',
  message: 'd'
}, {
  position: 'right',
  message: 'e'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'f'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'g'
}]

console.log(data.reduce((a, { position, message }, i, arr) => {
  const lastPosition = arr[i - 1]?.position;
  if (lastPosition !== position) a.push([]);
  a[a.length - 1].push(message);
  return a
}, []))
```

Without `.reduce`, and probably more readably:

```js
const data = [{
  position: 'left',
  message: 'a'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'b'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'c'
}, {
  position: 'right',
  message: 'd'
}, {
  position: 'right',
  message: 'e'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'f'
}, {
  position: 'left',
  message: 'g'
}];

let lastPosition;
const result = [];
for (const { position, message } of data) {
  if (position !== lastPosition) result.push([]);
  result[result.length - 1].push(message);
  lastPosition = position;
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group by looking to the previous object.

```js
const
    data = [{ position: 'left', message: 'a' }, { position: 'left', message: 'b' }, { position: 'left', message: 'c' }, { position: 'right', message: 'd' }, { position: 'right', message: 'e' }, { position: 'left', message: 'f' }, { position: 'left', message: 'g' }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o, i, a) => {
        if (o.position !== a[i - 1]?.position) r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```